# Can Foundy's Public Slate App Display Images in the app, or only links?

Tags: foundry-slate

Can someone please clarify if a Public Slate app will display an image (by adding Image widget), or it displays just the link to the image?

I have added the Image Widget to the app and provided the image source, which is a link to the image within Foundry environment. However, I want to know if I cannot display the image itself?